# Creating custom scheduler doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes

When I follow [these instructions](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/multiple-schedulers/) to create custom scheduler, the pods assigned to `my-scheduler` (`pod annotation-second-scheduler` in the example) keep status Pending and are never scheduled.

I think this is because the `kube-scheduler` cannot access the master from within the pod. I don't know how to get this working. How can the master be accessed from within a pod? I tried running `kubectl proxy -p 8001` in the pod, but this doesn't work.

Comment: So I found out why it wasn't working. I tried to use the example in combination with my local cluster. When running it in a GCE cluster, it works. I'll try to run it [locally](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/). This will probably work as well.

Answer (score 4):

There are few issues with the instructions mentioned in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/ for local clusters that I created using the instructions mentioned in https://blog.tekspace.io/setup-kubernetes-cluster-with-ubuntu-16-04/

These errors were reported from custom scheduler container (kubect logs command):

```
E0628 21:05:29.128618       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list persistentvolumeclaims at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.129945       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list services at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.132968       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: storageclasses.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list storageclasses.storage.k8s.io at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.151367       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: persistentvolumes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list persistentvolumes at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.152097       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1beta1.ReplicaSet: replicasets.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list replicasets.extensions at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.153187       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:594: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list pods at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.153201       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.Node: nodes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list nodes at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.153300       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list replicationcontrollers at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.153338       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: poddisruptionbudgets.policy is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list poddisruptionbudgets.policy at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:29.153757       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1beta1.StatefulSet: statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list statefulsets.apps at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:30.147954       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: storageclasses.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list storageclasses.storage.k8s.io at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:30.149547       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list persistentvolumeclaims at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
E0628 21:05:30.149562       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list services at the cluster scope: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kube-scheduler" not found
```

The issue is in the my-scheduler.yaml file: in roleref change the name field from kube-scheduler to system:kube-scheduler. Verify it using this command before changing the yaml file:

```
 kubectl get clusterrole  --all-namespaces | grep -i kube
```

It should list system:kube-scheduler instead of kube-scheduler only.

Then, it might print these errors in the custom scheduler container:

```
E0628 21:22:39.937271       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: storageclasses.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list storageclasses.storage.k8s.io at the cluster scope
E0628 21:22:40.940461       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: storageclasses.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list storageclasses.storage.k8s.io at the cluster scope
E0628 21:22:41.943323       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: storageclasses.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list storageclasses.storage.k8s.io at the cluster scope
E0628 21:22:42.946263       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.StorageClass: storageclasses.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:my-scheduler" cannot list storageclasses.storage.k8s.io at the cluster scope
```

In this case, please append these lines:

```
- apiGroups:
  - storage.k8s.io
  resources:
  - storageclasses
  verbs:
  - watch
  - list
  - get
```

to the end of the output of this command (this opens a file for you to edit):

```
kubectl edit clusterrole system:kube-scheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [user guide section on accessing the cluster API from a pod at kubernetes.io](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod):

> When accessing the API from a pod, locating and authenticating to the
>   api server are somewhat different.
>
> The recommended way to locate the apiserver within the pod is with the
>   kubernetes DNS name, which resolves to a Service IP which in turn will
>   be routed to an apiserver.
>
> The recommended way to authenticate to the apiserver is with a service
>   account credential. By kube-system, a pod is associated with a service
>   account, and a credential (token) for that service account is placed
>   into the filesystem tree of each container in that pod, at
>   `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`.
>
> If available, a certificate bundle is placed into the filesystem tree
>   of each container at
>   `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt`, and should be
>   used to verify the serving certificate of the apiserver.
>
> Finally, the default namespace to be used for namespaced API
>   operations is placed in a file at
>   `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace in each
>   container`.
>
> From within a pod the recommended ways to connect to API are:
>
> - run a kubectl proxy as one of the containers in the pod, or as a    background process within a container. This proxies the Kubernetes
>     API to the localhost interface of the pod, so that other processes in 
>     any container of the pod can access it. See this example of using
>     kubectl proxy in a pod.
> - use the Go client library, and create a    client using the client.NewInCluster() factory. This handles locating    and
>     authenticating to the apiserver.
>
> In each case, the credentials of the pod are used to communicate
>   securely with the apiserver.